# append form field to url

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to append a value (quantity) from a text input field to a url. Of course I can't get this to work.

What I've got is:

```
<form class="formProduct" id="formProduct" action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="formProductQuantity" value="{{ product.stock.minimum }}" /> // text field with quantity
<a class="button blue opener" href="" title="{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}"><span>{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}</span></a> // submit button
</form>

<script>
 var addUrl = "http://shop.com/cart/add/123456/?quantity="; // 123456 is the product id

asset("#formProduct");

function asset(product){

    $(product + " input#formProductQuantity").val("1");
    $(product + " #formProductQuantity").keyup(function () {
         var val = $(product + " input#formProductQuantity").first().val();
    });

    $(product + " .opener").click(function() {
           var val = $(product + " input#formProductQuantity").first().val();

              // Go to page
              window.location.href = addUrl + val;

    });
 }
 </script>
```

So what I try is to pass the quantity filled in the form to pass to http://shop.com/cart/add/123456/?quantity=100 for example. 
The code above I found on this forum but I can't get this to work.

Any help more then welcome

**UPDATE**

Ok thx to all the help here I got it to work. Any comments or modifications are still more then welcome. Function code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var addUrl = "http://shop.com/cart/add/123456/?quantity="; // 123456  is the product id

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  asset("#formProduct");
  });
 function asset(product){

jQuery(product + " input#formProductQuantity").val("1");
jQuery(product + " #formProductQuantity").keyup(function () {
     var val = jQuery(product + " input#formProductQuantity").first().val();
});

jQuery(product + " .opener").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
   $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data, status) {
       var val = jQuery(product + " input#formProductQuantity").first().val();

          // Go to page
          window.location.href = addUrl + val;
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
          return false;

  });
 })}
```

Comment: skashi's answer should work (+1). I was just about to suggest the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add Javascript to the submit button so it will run through the Javascript but the form will still be submitted, therefore window.location.href won't take place. What you need to do is add

> return false;

to the end of your asset() function:

```
$(product + " .opener").click(function() {
    var val = $(product + " input#formProductQuantity").first().val();

    // Go to page
    window.location.href = addUrl + val;
    return false;
});
```

This will stop the form from submitting, allowing your window.location.href to redirect as you required.

Comment: I tried this but now the url looks like a normal url. Like so: http://shop.com/productname. Where "productname" is the actual seo product name. When I change the empty "href" in the form to http://shop.com/cart/add/123456/?quantity= the url looks ok but then the quantity isn't passed to "quantity= ". Obviously there's something wrong in the code then, perhaps I need something like onclick= addUrl + val or something like that? My skills are limited so bear with me.

Comment: This is working for me. I had to wrap the jQuery code in :
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      //code
    });

See my completed code example: http://pastebin.com/TbkLMc5F

Comment: It seems that your script doesn't work in Chrome and IE. Or at least the update I've done to the script. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I ran your script locally and it seems to be working fine on Chrome. I'm on Ubuntu so can't test IE at the moment. Your added line:
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
seems to be giving issues but I think it is because I don't have a div with that ID or dialog is not defined for me.

Comment: Use pastebin.com and paste your entire code and I'll try see what's happening there

Comment: Thx for your help but I decided to use the jquery form plugin. My company asked to do this for them because I know a little bit of html, jquery and css, and they asked to do it fast :) So that's why I used the plugin which also works together with part of you code. I've replaced the snippet in your post above with the ajaxSubmit form the plugin which now works on all browsers. You're right about the dialog which causes the problems in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use get method to submit form it will send your data through url

Comment: Yes that's true, thanks for that! But this doesn't seems to work neither. I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. Do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  If you want the val in #formProductQuantity then use this:

```
var val = $("#formProductQuantity").val();

var addUrl = "http://shop.com/cart/add/123456/?quantity=" + val
top.location = addUrl
```

Update the href in your function:
{{ 'Add to cart' | t }} // submit button

In your function add this:

```
$(".opener").attr("href", "http://shop.com/cart/add/123456/?quantity=" + val );
```

Now the anchor is set and ready to go...Then when they click the anchor, away we go :-)  You can also add target="_blank" to open the url in a new page.

Comment: Thanks for your input and suggestions. Again this doesn't work. Apparently the link keeps changing back to a normal url like mentioned above. Obviously I have to put a link in the empty href or action. Then jquery should pass the quantity to that particularly url perhaps this can be done with an "onclick" or something?! Can you help me with that? +1 for your help ;)

Comment: I dont want to be a pain in the ... but how would the complete function looks like? The first time it worked the second time it doesn't anymore... I think I changed something but can't recall it.